# Major Dev tool issue- displaying my website half screen on all desktops

Tags: javascript, css

I was following the instructions in this youtube video 
'detecting critical css for above the fold content'
the link to the video is:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfmUf1_M9lI

I was following this to try and find my above the fold content to in turn fix the problem - Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content from my website -

www.kookabig.com.au

if you view my website you will see that its now only displaying on the left side of the screen and is no longer full page width

i have resored my website from a back up before i attempted to eliminate the 'render blocking javascript' but it remains in the same left sided view

i really need help

have never used the dev tools before yesterday and have no idea what i have done to end up with this outcome any other information needed to help on this just let me know

any solutions trouble shooting or things i can try to fix would be so greatly beyond appreciated !

thank you in advance

Tegan

Comment: you're setting a fixed width on `#container`

Comment: sorry dan i am a real newbie 
how would i be able to fix that or where do i find the #container?

Comment: He means `<div id="container">`

Comment: }
@media screen and (max-width: 830px)
.container {

Comment: this is the width i can find in that div id container if this is where i am meant to make a change could you please advise the px for full width

Comment: i also found under elements and properties div #container.container theres an 'offset width : 206 ' in there where everything else is 0 is that the problem?